# Adding an index to a multi-billion (around 160 billion) row table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am about to add an index for one of the 6 columns in a table with 160 billion rows in postgres. At the present time, I envisage that this table will mostly remain as is, without further updates to it. While this can be done, of course, through a normal CREATE INDEX command on a column "my_column" in a table "my_table":

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name ON my_table(my_column);
```

This is going to be extremely slow - not exactly sure how long this is going to take, but likely several days, judging by performance of the CREATE INDEX command on smaller tables. Is there any way to optimize the creation of an index for such a large table in postgres?

Comment: Apart from using faster hardware there is no option to make this faster. If you are worried about the table being locked during the creation, you can use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` which will take even longer, but will allow concurrent read & write access to the table. You can monitor the progress through [pg_stat_progress_create_index ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In a similar fashion, when creating the table, I did not add a primary key constraint as with some testing, this proved to slow down the import of data (data was previously stored in csvs) from 2 days to over a week. How long can I expect the addition of a primary key (using 2 of the columns) to take, as a rough estimate? Is there some way to check status of a primary key addition (or index addition)?

Comment: How fast is your hardware?

Comment: I am running this on a cluster, on a node with 80 Intel Xeon Gold 6230 processors at a processor speed of 2.10GHz each, with 775Gb of RAM available on the system. I don't think it is possible to make use of multi-processing for SQL indexing though?

Comment: As already mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't think you can avoid the burden of indexing such a large table. It will inevitably take some time. With such a large table, my first instinct would be to create partitions or even sharding, so that interventions like that become more palatable. Good luck!

Comment: This depends on the version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is a good idea written by @a_horse_with_no_name. And for this large data, it is recommended to use table partitions and partitioned indexing. Your device settings are fine. I think that creating an index in PostgreSQL won't take too long, it won't take days